# Частные методы JavaScript (es 6)

Tags: javascript

Каким образом лучше писать частные методы(свойства) в классах в JavaScript?

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this._privateMethod()
  }
  _privateMethod() {

  }
}

const MyClass1 = (function() {
  const privateMethod = () => {

  }

  class MyClass1 {
    constructor() {
      privateMethod()
    }
  }
  return MyClass1
}());

const a = new MyClass();
console.log(a._privateMethod);
```

#### Первый вопрос:

В **MyClass** метод доступен в прототипе. Это хорошо, плохо или нормально?

#### Второй вопрос:

Следует отдавать предпочтение **MyClass1** с замыканием?

Или предложите свой вариант.
Спасибо.